# Using ifconfig to check whether I'm on local WiFi or 3G

Tags: iphone, bash, ip, wifi, ifconfig

For a bash script I want to determine whether my device has Wi-Fi. The easiest way for me would be ifconfig and some regex. 
So I want to check if my interface en0 has a valid IP or not.

```
ifconfig en0 | grep inet | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2}'
```

gives me the IP. If I dont have one it doesn't return anyhting since the `grep` command returns nothing. How do I check for that in an `if` for example?

Comment: How does this help with checking for the presence of WiFi? `en0` could be a cable connection.

Comment: Well that interface is the WiFi Interface. So if it has an IP, I definately am on WiFi. Plus, I dont have an Ethernet Interface (iPhone).

Comment: Both of you are correct. The `en0` interface on the iPhone **is** WI-Fi, but on an actual computer it could be Wi-Fi **or** ethernet.

Comment: Ah now I seem to understand the difference. on a PC let's say eth0 would be the physical, maybe ethernet, interface and eth1 another physical (maybe wifi) interface. Whereas en0 is an interface for both?

Comment: @tzippy I am not able to find ip for en0 in my mac, Is this normal? But I see I can find ip for en1.

Comment: Actually I was referring to iPhone not mac. On mac this can actually be different.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put this together with info I found on other sites.

```
#!/bin/sh
IP_ADDRESS=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2}')
IP_ADDR_VAL=$(echo "$IP_ADDRESS" | grep -Ec '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])')

if [ $IP_ADDR_VAL -eq 0 ]; then
   echo not valid
else 
   echo valid
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I noticed the `inet` part being only there when I'm connected, so a piped `grep inet`  should do the job just fine!

Answer (score -1):

my ifconfig output is different

```
inet addr:192.168.210.140  Bcast:192.168.215.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
inet6 addr: fe80::92fb:a6ff:fe66:970/64 Scope:Link
```

however the difference is not great u will find out what u need to change (I understand u need to check one interface - here eth0; every interface has one inet line)

```
if [[ `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -e 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f12 | grep -E "^addr:[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}$" | wc -l` -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "correct IP";
else
  echo "no IP";
fi
echo " assigned";
```

Comment: your 'cut -d ' ' -f12' command doesnt seem to return anthing.

Comment: i've got this '  (lots of spaces)        inet addr:192.168.210.140  Bcast:192.168.215.255  Mask:255.255.248.0' after `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -e 'inet '`. u need to check what your grep prints and adjust cut option -f.